# How to generically type React component props and extend the generic props type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component where the element type is parameterized. I'd like to type this component so you can specify the type of the element and constrain the props to that type.

```
interface IProps<T> extends T {
  elementName: string,
}

class Foo<T> extends React.Component<IProps<T>, {}> {
  render() {
    const { elementName, ...props } = this.props;
    return React.createElement(elementName, {
        ...props,
    });
  }
}
```

For example, `href` is a valid prop when the type of the props is `AnchorHTMLAttributes` but not when it's `HTMLAttributes`.

```
// Ok
<Foo<AnchorHTMLAttributes<AnchorHTMLElement>> href="foo.com"/>

// Type checker error because `href` is not an attribute of a div
<Foo<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> href="foo.com"/>
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like type you want is:

```
React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
```

Swap out both `Input`'s for other types of tags.

And it looks like the most generic constraint would be:

```
React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>
```

Then you can merge that type with something that gives you your `elementName`. With the constraint and the `elementName` you get:

```
function Foo<T extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>(
  props: T & { elementName: string },
) {
  const { elementName, ...otherProps } = props
  return React.createElement(elementName, otherProps)
}
```

Or as a class component:

```
class Foo<T extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>> extends React.Component<
  T & { elementName: string }
> {
  render() {
    const { elementName, ...otherProps } = this.props
    return React.createElement(elementName, otherProps)
  }
}
```

Usage works like you seem to expect, though you will have to provide `elementName`.

```
function App() {
    return <>
        <Foo<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>
          elementName="input"
          value={1}
        /> {/* valid */}

        <Foo<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>>
          elementName="input"
          href='/foo/bar'
        /> {/* Property 'href' does not exist on type */}
    </>
}
```

[Working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=8&ssc=21&pln=8&pc=54#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCswFcA7DYCeuAMQggB4AVOJAB4wk9ACYBnRMRgA6ABI8AsgBkAgjBhRgAI1rDxXBSoCiAGyQgRMAHzWAFGBxhxALjh8AZHADe-c5foYADkUSzdxTWB6AHM4AF8ASh8qOFS4NBYInyR-KxDLABo4GRKIGAALJCgABSdxOLgAXjhHCGcUtKIYWihWZHRZNCIUYTMLKzsc8cD8pCKyypq6hKo4qio0UxRxSQAhFChefiERCSkB+SU1DS1dfUMrsYCba2PhMUl+jBkAYVxIehWLjuOBeXxTZ6zcKRGLxOCvbwdVJEMRVOxJRGUNLY9KZeDeCF5UJzYqlCpVWptepNOAVYDiGStdpYnHIpDdXrnb5DVCjXKBSb84LE+bkpZUlYs1JrSgymgMJgsOCqMBgdHJKVwLo9VhcaxInFcDjcL6yACS9DAeiM10idyQBhtFqtMCeVlsfmmwssjXwURd+DgADcUKZaEhGt4AIwNAD0+s12KNnC4ppkzutV3Udr0DoeKgzrqFHsJM2Jvv9ekD5SImEaAHJY5hOLHtAd63B4+tE2kuPtDmnCzbs7dc46roW3YES0LZhXLVXg6Hw5GY52E6zUn2DqnpOmFzBhzcdGP88pJ8XXqXvRG-Qfq7WG02W22oB2u5quB+4kA)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this and it gave me an error about `className` not being a prop but I realized that was because I was accessing it on `otherProps` and not `this.props`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this type, it extends React.HTMLAttributes and includes props from other elements:

```
React.AllHTMLAttributes<unknown>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).